# generating a histogram in R causing an error

Tags: r, graph, histogram

I have data saved in a text file named "timemapreport.txt" that I am trying to import to RStudio and generate a histogram for it:

The data is saved in a text file in this format:

```
12
16
1025
965
9
1
9
9
12
```

I tried to use this code but it is generating an error:
The data is being read in RStudio. I think it's fine. However when I try to generate the histogram, it failed because of an error. I did some search online and it says that R is reading the data but considering it as a string, not numbers, so I tried to convert it to numeric or integer, but that still did not work.

I took out some of the arguments for the function hist() to see which one is causing the error, but that did not work either. I even reduced the argument to just one argument, but still no luck!

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

```
> timemaps_data <- read.table("C:/R/timemapreport.txt", header=F, sep="\t")
> View(timemaps_data)
> View(timemaps_data)
> max_num <- max(timemaps_data)
> hist(timemaps_data, col=heat.colors(max_num), breaks=max_num, xlim=c(0,max_num), right=F, main="Mementos Histogram", las=1)
Error in hist.default(timemaps_data, col = heat.colors(max_num), breaks = max_num,  : 
  'x' must be numeric
> hist(timemaps_data, col=heat.colors(max_num), breaks=max_num, xlim=c(0:max_num), right=F, main="Mementos Histogram", las=1)
Error in hist.default(timemaps_data, col = heat.colors(max_num), breaks = max_num,  : 
  'x' must be numeric
> hist(timemaps_data, breaks=max_num, xlim=c(0,max_num), right=F, main="Mementos Histogram", las=1)
Error in hist.default(timemaps_data, breaks = max_num, xlim = c(0, max_num),  : 
  'x' must be numeric
> hist(timemaps_data, breaks=max_num, right=F, main="Mementos Histogram", las=1)
Error in hist.default(timemaps_data, breaks = max_num, right = F, main = "Mementos Histogram",  : 
  'x' must be numeric
> hist(timemaps_data, right=F, main="Mementos Histogram", las=1)
Error in hist.default(timemaps_data, right = F, main = "Mementos Histogram",  : 
  'x' must be numeric
> hist(timemaps_data, main="Mementos Histogram", las=1)
Error in hist.default(timemaps_data, main = "Mementos Histogram", las = 1) : 
  'x' must be numeric
> hist(timemaps_data, main="Mementos Histogram")
Error in hist.default(timemaps_data, main = "Mementos Histogram") : 
  'x' must be numeric
> hist(timemaps_data)
Error in hist.default(timemaps_data) : 'x' must be numeric
> hist(timemaps_data, col="lightblue", ylim=c(0,10))
Error in hist.default(timemaps_data, col = "lightblue", ylim = c(0, 10)) : 
  'x' must be numeric
> timemaps_data <- read.table("C:/R/timemapreport.txt", header=F, sep="\n")
> max_num <- max(timemaps_data)
> hist(timemaps_data, col=heat.colors(max_num), breaks=max_num, xlim=c(0,max_num), right=F, main="Mementos Histogram", las=1)
Error in hist.default(timemaps_data, col = heat.colors(max_num), breaks = max_num,  : 
  'x' must be numeric
> timemaps_data <- as.numeric(timemaps_data) 
Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
> timemaps_data <- as.int(timemaps_data) 
Error: could not find function "as.int"
> timemaps_data <- as.integer(timemaps_data) 
Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'
> timemaps_data <- as.integer(timemaps_data) 
Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'
```

Comment: `numeric` is a class. When you see an error like "must be numeric", it means your data is of the wrong class. You should look at `class(timemaps_data)` or `str(timemaps_data)` to see what it really is - that can help you figure out the problem.

Comment: Your problem most likely lies in your data itself. My bet is the last end of line of your file. But could be a character somewhere that is not a number. If that hypothesis is true, either clean your data before importing or filter any value that can not be coerced to a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you're supplying `hist()` with a `data.frame` as its argument when it only knows how to deal with a single column of a `data.frame`. Try this:

```
timemaps_data <- read.table("C:/R/timemapreport.txt", header=F, sep="\t")
hist(timemaps_data[,1])
```

or:

```
timemaps_data <- read.table("C:/R/timemapreport.txt", header=F, sep="\t")
names(timemaps_data)
hist(timemaps_data$V1)
```

"V1" is the default name for a data.frame's columns if you don't name them

Comment: Both solutions worked.. Thank you. However, the histogram is not the best looking one because the data varies too much. I wanted to make the bin size is 1 so data on the x axis is not grouped together, and make each value look like a bar. If there is no frequency for a value in the x axis, then remove it to make room for the ones with frequency. I tried this code, but not what I wanted. I am happy just to be able to generate a histogram. Thank you.. hist(timemaps_data$V1, col=heat.colors(max_num), breaks=max_num, xlim=c(0,max_num), right=F, main="Mementos Histogram", las=1)